# How to get NSNumber value length?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to check total digit count from NSNumber. Most easy way is to convert it to NSString and then check its length. The other way would be to take integer value, perform loop by dividing with 10. Just wondering are there other options :)

Comment: Converting to a string and then getting the length could get you into trouble if there is a decimal or `-` sign.

Comment: Yes, but I'm checking positive numbers only (credit card numbers), so that should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `log10()` function will get you close.  Something like:

```
ceil (log10 (x))
```

for example:

```
> ceil (log10 (200))
3
> ceil (log10 (9999))
4
```

Maybe add in an `fabs` as:

```
ceil (log10 (fabs (x)))
```

For fractional numbers, the above wouldn't work.  But, you could try splitting into integer+fraction and working on the two independently.

Comment: Thanks. Is this solution by anything better from converting number to string and checking length, in terms of ... maybe performance, clean code and etc? Because log10 + ceil looks like computational  overhead for such simple operation (especially for positive numbers). So, I think I will fallback to using convertToString + strLengh solution.

Comment: Converting to string and checking the length is definitely more readable.

Comment: I just provided another option.  For me, what I use would depend on the application.  But, one thing for sure, efficiency/performance for such a low-level computation, would never factor in.  As for readability, one should wrap the above `log` based solution in another function, say `fdigit_count(x)`.